# How to setup logstash to forward logs to another logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have a few web servers which has logstash installed, and I have a log server which also has logstash installed.

I want forward logs in web servers `/var/log/nginx/*log`  to log server using logstash. Is it possible?

web server:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/nginx/*log"
  }
}
output {
  tcp {
    host => "log.server.ip"
    port => 12345
  }
}
```

log server:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 12345
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

but no logs are forwarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use [logstash-forwarder](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder) or preferably the newest [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) (logstash-forwarder replacement) tool on the web server and Logstash with the [`beats` input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html) on the log server.

So your Filebeat configuration on the web server should look like this:

```
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
    # Each - is a prospector. Below are the prospector specific configurations
    -
      paths:
        - "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
      document_type: weblog 
      fields:
        service: nginx

output:
  logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts. 
    hosts:
      - log.server.ip:12345
```

And your Logstash configuration on the log server would look like this

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 12345
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

If you don't want to install Filebeat on the web server because you want to leverage your existing Logstash, it is also possible. The Logstash configuration on your web server needs to use the [`lumberjack` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-lumberjack.html) like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/nginx/*log"
  }
}
output {
  lumberjack {
    hosts => "log.server.ip"
    port => 12345
    ssl_certificate => "/path/to/certificate.pub"
  }
}
```

And on your log server, you'd need to use the [`lumberjack` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html):

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 12345
    ssl_certificate => "/path/to/certificate.cer"
    ssl_key => "/path/to/certificate.key"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```